# Me and my graphing calculator disagree with Wolfram Alpha's result concerning the following function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

$$\frac{x - \arcsin(2 x)}{x^{0.6} \tanh(3 x)} $$

Can you help me make sure which is the correct domain? Why does Wolfram Alpha remove the part on the left despite it being in the domain?

---

I got the domain for this function by intersecting the domains of each of the smaller functions inside it and it was from -1/2 to 1/2 where x is never equal to zero , I checked the graph of the function using Desmos app and it showed me a graph having the same domain I solved , but when I did the same on Wolfram Alpha it showed that the domain is from 0 to 1/2 (excluding zero) , I am sure of my calculations but I don't understand why does Wolfram Alpha show me this false graph , domain

Comment: You are missing a few *crucial* pieces of information. Namely, what do your calculators and Wolfram Alpha "tell" you? (And what do *you* think about which one is correct?)

Comment: What's $(-1)^{0.6}$? It depends on whether you compute it as $(-1)^{6/10}$ or $(-1)^{3/5}$. Raising to a non integer power is only sensibly defined for positive base.

Comment: @ClementC. Sure

Comment: @egreg Oh , I didn't know about that so you are telling me that the domains of x^(3/5) , x^(6/10) , x^(0.6) are in some way different?

Comment: In math, once beyond certain level, raising a negative number to a non-integral power will be treated as a complex number. The domain for $x^{3/5}, x^{6/10}, x^{0.6}$ (as a real function) all becomes $(0,\infty)$. The only exception is when handling some algebra problem, one may (but not must) treat fractional power written out explicitly as a quotient of two odd number differently. e.g. $(-1)^{3/5} = -1$ but $(-1)^{6/10} = (-1)^{0.6} = e^{\frac{3\pi}{5} i}$ (for the default branch). So WA is right, Desmos is probably wrong. Your calculator may be right because of its targeted base of users.

Comment: @achillehui so that's why ....I think for each of those '-1' is one of the roots(Demoiver's) , but they are still complex numbers , alright thanks I got it now 

Comment: You should find the domain by inspecting and thinking about the given expression, and not by comparing various internet sources.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Okay , Thanks for the advice .